# How to solve this ode with absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(t)$ be continuously differentiable, $y(0)>0$, and $$|y'(t)|=|y(t)|, t\geq 0.$$

Then how to show that $y(t)=y(0)e^{t}$ or $y(t)=y(0)e^{-t}$.

The main difficulty lies in that I could not prove $$y'(t)=y(t),$$ for all $t>0$ or $$y'(t)=-y(t)$$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: these two cases are the only possible one cases

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How can I prove these are the possible ones? thanks.